# O365 SharePoint Site - How to replace the default Master Page?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365

We created an HTML file with Office Fabric UI to make it responsive. Our intention is to integrate the HTML file we created with O365 SharePoint site and make it as our Intranet Home Page.

So, please let us know how to replace the default Master Page with our custom file. Any pointers to appropriate pages would be very helpful.

Account Info: Office 365 Business Essentials with SharePoint Online (Plan 1).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set a new masterpage will have to upload it to the Masterpage Library which is located at: https://domain.sharepoint.com/_catalogs/masterpage

To assign the masterpage to your site go to Site Settings > Design Manager > Publish and Apply Design > Assign master pages to your site based on device channel.

Choose your Masterpage from the dropdowns, specify whether you want to "Reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting" or not. Then hit OK.

After a refresh you should see your new masterpage in action.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I couldn't find the Design Manager Link. Our aim is to integrate the custom HTML created with the existing Master Page.

Comment: When you can't find the _Design Manager_ link in _Site Settings_, please go to _Site Settings > Site Collection Features _ and activate _SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure_. Once activated you will see the _Design Manager_ link.

Comment: Hi. I assume the problem with activating SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure is, SharePoint won't allow us to save the site as a template to be used later (I maybe completely wrong here). We have to include the HTML and CSS with sandbox site and after getting prior approval, the site has to be downloaded as a template and integrated with Home Page on our Production server. Since, I'm pretty new to SharePoint, not sure whether this is right approach. Thanks.

Comment: Branding SharePoint without using Publishing Infrastructure is not recommended (but possible) and (if i remember correctly) will not create a master-file from your HTML-template. So in that case you will probably have to directly customize the master-file instead.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for the response. The only reason we didn't activate Publishing Infrastructure feature because, SP won't support 'Download as Template' option once it's activated. Is directly customizing the master file is recommended? If so, SharePoint designer would be suffice or we need Visual Studio to make the changes? Thanks.

Comment: Editing the master-file is absolutely fine and SPD is sufficient to do that.